# is there a chinese version of ex. as in example?

Tags: abbreviations

Is there a version of ex. in Chinese, as in the abbreviation of example? I know theres 例子 but anything quicker than that?

Comment: Not enough rep for a comment. Please be aware that "ex", while occasionally used, is a poor abbreviation for "example" in English. Its dominant meaning is "former", as in "ex-spouse" or "ex-President", and if you're lucky and a reader realizes that this isn't what was intended, will perhaps think of "excluding" or "except". The normal and extremely well-documented abbreviation for "example" is "e.g.". Anyone who hasn't seen it and needs to look it up will immediately find the right meaning, which is not going to be the case for "ex".

Comment: FYI, the abbreviation of "example" is "e.g.". The word "ex" instead means "former".

Answer (score 7):

In writing, you can just write 例.

For instance.

例：足球、篮球、乒乓球

Comment: For what it's worth 例 is also recognizable in Japanese. Albeit pronounced as rei instead of lì.

Comment: Or you could say 如：足球、篮球、乒乓球

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to say "Example" in Chinese. **例 (ex.):** 例如, 例子, 比如, 譬如.

Answer (score 1):

比如、例如、譬如  are three common ways to say "for example/such as"-- along with their variations such as a simple 例。

Like all chinese vocab: which to choose will vary by context, formality, sentence structure, and personal preference etc.

This is far from exhaustive but should help give you a full and short way to say this term.